# Regularity of fundamental solution to heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $u(x)=\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{2t}}g(y)\, dy,\quad x\in \mathbb{R}$ be the fundamental solution to 
$$\begin{cases} u_t-\frac{1}{2}u_{xx}=0, &t\in (0,T],x\in \mathbb{R},\\ u(0,x)=g(x),&x\in \mathbb{R}.\end{cases}$$

I am considering the following problem: suppose $g$ is nice enough, does there exist $p>2$ and constant $C=C(p,g)$, such that 
$$\|D_x u\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R})}\le C, \; \forall t\in (0,T].$$

---

Formally, by using the PDE and the identity $2DuDu_t=\frac{d}{dt}(|Du|^2)$, I got 
$$\|D_x u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}\le C\|D_xg\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}.$$

Answer (score 2):

First, let me suggest carefulness when dealing with your equation. Your ``fundamental solution'' is a solution of the problem, and the only such that $u \to 0$ as $|x| \to +\infty$ (this condition is satisfied in L^p. Unless you add this condition, the problem you study is ill posed.

Also, when you bound the norms, you should be careful, since you are forgetting the time variable.

If you are looking for solutions $u \in W^{1,p}$ then your best bet is to think about the evolution semigroup, which can be studied by the eigenvalue decomposition of the $-\Delta$ operator.

In a bounded domain $\Omega$ (an I guess you extend that to unbounded domains) you can expect
$$ \| \nabla u (\cdot, t) \|_{L^2 (\Omega)} + \| u (\cdot, t) \|_{L^2 (\Omega)} \le C t^{-\frac 1 2} \| g \|_{L^2 (\Omega)} $$

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. So in general, the norm of derivative will blow up?

Comment: As $t\to 0$, if your data is not smooth yes (logically). If the data is smooth, then there are better estimates towards 0.  Actually, the estimate I gave should be consider towards infinity. Locally $u \to 0$ as $t \to +\infty$, and it does so in the $H^1$ norm.

Comment: I see. But I care more about the behavior for $t\to 0$ and the data is smooth enough.

Comment: For every $t>0$ your solution is as smooth as you would like. Besides there is always a estimate of the form $\| D^n u \|_{L^p} \le C t ^{-\alpha} \| g \|_{L^2}$. As $t \to 0$ you cannot expect more regularity that $g$ has. In that sense, if $g \in X$ a functional space, then you can expect $u \in \mathcal C ([0,t_0], X)$, but, of course, nothing better.

Comment: @JohnZHANG : Because of the equation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=k\nabla^2u$, the heat semigroup solution operator $T(t)$ turns $H^{2s}$ spatial data into $H^{s}$ time data. There's a way to make that precise in $L^2$. More roughly, if the initial spatial data is $C^{2\alpha}$ Holder then the time dependence is *almost* $C^{\alpha}$ in time (everything up to that.)